# Перевод заголовков в секциях учётной записи пользователя

Tags: поддержка, локализация, термины

[Предмет обсуждения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/discord).

Имеющиеся заголовки:

- 0 – общее количество ответов
- 0 вопросов
- 1учетная запись
- 101 репутация

Оригинал:

- 0 Answers
- 0 Questions
- 1 Account
- 101 Reputation

Пока опустим вопрос раздолбайства с "общим количеством" и отсутствущими пробелами. Давайте обратим внимание, что это **заголовки**. То, что сейчас имеется, как заголовки не выглядит. Привести заголовки в вид, соответствующий правилам русского языка, при этом сохранив лаконичность, опрятность и презентабельность, невозможно, потому что в этом случае правила предписывают избавляться от цифр и писать числа словами. Как мне кажется, в данном конкретном случае можно нарушить формальные правила и сделать красиво.

Какой вариант вам больше по душе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Число + строчная буква:

- 10 ответов
- 10 вопросов
- 10 учётных записей
- 100 очков репутации

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Число + заглавная буква:

  - 10 Ответов
  - 10 Вопросов
  - 10 Учётных записей
  - 100 Очков репутации
- Вырвиглазное нечто от оригинальных переводчиков:

  - 10 — общее количество ответов
  - 10 — общее количество вопросов
  - 10 — общее количество учётных записей
  - 100 — общее количество очков репутации
- Число после заголовка:

  - Ответов: 10
  - Вопросов: 10
  - Учётных записей: 10
  - Очков репутации: 100
- Изменить разметку, оставив слово слева, а число поместить справа:

  Ответов                         10
  Вопросов                        10
  Учётных записей                 10
  Очков репутации                100